# How do I determine the indirect object of a command?

Tags: grammar, imperatives

I'm working my way through the core 2000, and came across this:

> [明日]{あす}、6[時]{じ}に[起]{お}こしてください。

I immediately thought, "Please wake up at 6am tomorrow." But the translation in the deck instead says, "Please wake **me** up tomorrow at six o'clock."

How would I know who the indirect object (the person being woken up) is? Shouldn't "wake me up" be preceded by [私]{わたし}に or similar?

Comment: By the way, "me" is the DIRECT object in "wake me up". In Japanese, it is also a direct object, so if it were to be there, it would be 私を.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, you are confusing transitive (起こす) and intransitive (起きる) verbs. Your "immediate thought" would be

> Please wake up at 6am tomorrow.
>   明日、6時に **起きて** ください。

Secondly, you should keep in mind that the direct object (here, of the transitive verb 起こす) may be omitted, whence

> 明日、6時に起こしてください。
>   Please wake [someone] up at 6am tomorrow.

where [someone] = me is implied.